# Show Entity Framework generated SQL for Insert / Update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity

Is it possible, from code, to see the generated SQL for an insert/update ?
I need it by code because I am using a database that does not permit to show SQL queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a demo of the entity framework profiler

Entity Framework Profiler
http://efprof.com/

Maybe this might be of help..
http://blog.cincura.net/227674-how-to-show-sql-command-created-by-entity-framework/

This question may well help you as well...
[Best way to show the SQL trace of a LINQ query to Entity Framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920990/best-way-to-show-the-sql-trace-of-a-linq-query-to-entity-framework-3-5)

Comment: If you are happy with this answer please could you mark this as the acceptable answer, so other people can find it in the future.. :)