# C# comparing OrderDate to variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have a variable, which differs between a day, a week, and a month. A form takes this and sends it back to the controller. However I am trying to get the "View orders within 1 week" to work using this method below. No errors, It just doesn't show any orders at all.

```
Controller; (Just trying to get it to work before i change the amount of days)
else if (date == "day")
            {
                DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime answer = today.AddDays(10);

                return View(db.Orders.Where(x => x.OrderDate <= answer).ToList());
            }
```

This is my view, including other parts I use;

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "EditOrders", FormMethod.Get))
{
    //the following are search options

    <b> Search for: </b>@Html.RadioButton("option", "FirstName") <text>First Name</text> @Html.RadioButton("option", "PostalCode") <text> Post-Code </text>
    @Html.RadioButton("option", "Username")<text>Email-Address</text> @Html.TextBox("search")
    <text>Orders Made </text><select id="date" name="date">
        <option value="none">No day</option>
        <option value="day">In the last day</option>
        <option value="week">In the last week</option>
        <option value="month">In the last month</option>
        <option value="year">In the last year</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Comment: To confirm (probably obvious) - what's the type of OrderDate in db.Orders.  Also to confirm, you're asking about a **week**, but checking for **== "day"** then adding 10 days - is this a typo in the question or does your code check for day twice and not week?

Comment: Have a look at this answer and output the generated sql - should help you find where the issue is:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920990/best-way-to-show-the-sql-trace-of-a-linq-query-to-entity-framework-3-5

Comment: @freedomn-m its a DateTime, yeah just for test purposes, if I can get it to check for 10 days, I can get it to check any. In the code, it sets today, then adds the days to today. I need it to show Orders where OrderDate is between "today" and "answer"

Comment: When you say _"It just doesn't show any orders at all."_, do you mean in the view? What is the code in the view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry that was vague, in the View it displays all the orders, however when I search for the "day" it displays no orders at all

Comment: The code you have shown will show all orders where `OrderDate` is less than 7th May 2016 if you run it today. (not clear what the issue is)

Comment: @StephenMuecke exactly what I thought, but it doesn't!

Comment: @StephenMuecke wait why would it show less than 7th may and not since 10 days ago?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is `27th April`. Plus 10 days is `7th May`

Comment: Your code is: OrderDate is *before* 10 days from now.   This means orders due(/created?) in the next 10 days and any overdue (ie including those before today), excluding any further in the future, but including all those in the past.  Hence the assumption that the unclear field "OrderDate" is order **due** date (ie which ones need to be completed asap because they're due).  If "OrderDate" is "date order raised" then your query makes no sense, *but should still work* as all order dates will before before today.

Comment: DateA < DateB means DateA is *before* DateB.  Smaller date = earlier in time.

Comment: @freedomn-m the OrderDate is the date that the order is placed, I'm trying to initialize a drop down box where the user can select, for instance, "Orders within 1 week" and it will show the orders made in the past week. So OrderDate < Answer in my code should display it, Im not sure why it doesn't

Comment: Yes - you want (OrderDate >= today-10days) - but either way doesn't explain why it's not working - what does the EF generated SQL look like?

Comment: Haha @freedomn-m it does work if my orders were made in the future. I was adding days and comparing it AddDays(10) not checking previous orders AddDays(-10), by looking at what you had said I managed to fix that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

My code is correct and works now, All I had to do was add a - to the add days to look in the past

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
                DateTime answer = today.AddDays(-10);
```